# Viscous Fluids at a Slope (Navier-Stokes)

Tags: dynamical-systems, physics, mathematical-physics, fluid-dynamics, viscosity-solutions

An in-compressible viscous fluid flows down a flat slope of angle θ to the
horizontal under the force of gravity, with g the acceleration due to gravity.
What are the boundary conditions for the fluid at the point of contact with
the slope and at the free surface?

***What I know:*** $u=0$ at $y=0$ and $\frac{du}{dy}=0$ at y=d. Then $\vec {g}=[g sin(a),-gcos(a),0]$

Using orthogonal coordinates with the x-axis pointing down the slope and
the y-axis perpendicular to the slope, find a solution to the Navier-Stokes
equation for a flow of depth d down the slope under the assumptions that
the flow is steady and uniform in the x-direction, including an expression
for the pressure.

*This is how i interpreted the question in a figure:*

[image: Flow down a Slope in two dimensions]

A river descends by 100m over a distance of 100km. Given that the dynamic viscosity of water is approximately $$\mu=10^{−3}kgm^{−1}s^{−1}$$ 
estimate the predicted speed of the river using your own estimates for any other
parameters involved.

Is it unrealistic? If so give possible reasons for the lack of realism.

***What I know:*** is the Navier-Stokes Equation is... $$\dfrac{d\vec{v}}{d t}+ \vec{v} .\nabla \vec{v} = \vec{F} -  \dfrac{1}{\rho} \nabla p + \nu \nabla^2 \vec{v}$$

Now I'm a bit unsure but I think due to the fluid being *in-compressible* we now have the equation: $$\dfrac{d\vec{v}}{d t}+ \vec{v} .\nabla \vec{v} = \vec{F} -  \dfrac{1}{\rho} \nabla p$$

Really stuck from here, on this question don't really know how to approach it as I'm fairly new to fluid dynamics any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are conflating incompressible with inviscid.  Here we have flow of an incompressible **viscous** fluid and the term $\nu \nabla^2 \mathbf{v}$ may not be neglected.

You are asked to find "a solution" under the assumptions that the flow is steady and uniform in the x-direction. This implies fully-developed unidirectional flow where the only non-vanishing component of velocity is $u$ (i.e., the component in the x-direction).

For an incompressible fluid, the equation of continuity gives

$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{v} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0$$

Thus, $u$ is a function only of the y-coordinate and the Navier-Stokes equations reduce to

$$0 = -\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial p}{\partial x} +g \sin \alpha + \nu \frac{d^2u}{dy^2}, \\0 = -\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial p}{\partial y} -g \cos \alpha $$

Since the flow is gravity-driven, we can neglect the x-component of the pressure pressure gradient $\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}$ in the first equation and find $u$ by applying the two boundary conditions to the solution of the second-order differential equation

$$\nu \frac{d^2 u}{dy^2} = -g \sin \alpha$$

The second equation allows for solution of the  pressure as a function of the y-coordinate.

See if you can finish now.

Comment: I got the answer after integrating twice: $u=-\frac{gy^2}{2v}sin(a)+Ay+B$, How would I go about calculating the speed with $\mu$ given? @RRL

Comment: @Reety:  Correct.  The boundary conditions you identified above are correct as well , so you can solve for A and B.  We get $B = 0$ etc.

Comment: so the final answer is $u=\frac{g}{2v}sina(2dy-y^2)$? and is this realistic?

Comment: So you can set $y = d$ to get the maximum velocity at the surface. They want you to plug in values for the river and see if you get a realistic speed.  They specified the viscosity $\mu$ so you need to get the kinematic viscosity $\nu = \mu/\rho$ by dividing by the density which is about $1 g/cm^3$ for water.  They give you enough information to find the angle. They don't tell you the depth $d$ but you can use a number like $10 m$.

Comment: aah right okay, ill try and figure it out now. Thank you very much!

Comment: The river descends 100 m over a distance of 100 km = 100,000 m. So $\tan \theta = 100/100000 = 0.001$. You also need to know that $g$ is approximately equal to $10 \, m \, s^2$.

Comment: Yeah my answers can't be right, I got $u=4.9*10^{5}$ using $d=10$, $\theta=10^{-3}$ and $v=10^{-6}$ @rrl 

edit: or maybe it is right and it's just not realistic, which in that case it's not realistic because.... I have no clue XD

Comment: That calculation is correct.  Even if the river is only 1 m deep you get a speed of about 5000 m per second which is not realistic.

Comment: why has this become unrealistic? and thank you so much for the help btw.

Comment: The question "warns" you that you might not get a realistic answer and you might need to explain. So I don't believe there is anything wrong. The viscous gravity driven flow solution is undoubtedly only realistic for thin layers of fluid sliding down a surface with small length scales like rainwater running down an inclined table.  The flow in a river is likely to be turbulent with velocity that is not unidirectional. There will be increased drag at the solid boundary that will prevent the fluid from going this fast.

Comment: That is my first suggestion.  I have to think about it and get back to you.  It's been a while since I worked in this field.  Nevertheless you know that the solution is correct if you are getting the right units --  meters per second -- which appears to be the case.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Let me know if you come up with any other observations as to why it's unrealistic. Thank you.